# How easy is it to receive a radio signal in Mandarin from BBC and VoA in Beijing?

Tags: media, censorship

How easy is it to receive a radio signal in Mandarin from BBC and VoA in Beijing? In other words, is it a good signal that you can listen to at any time of day with readily available equipment that is available at a low price?

Addendum...

@user103496 posted an answer with links that show that both the BBC and VoA were using shortwave radio and Aliexpress.com sells SW receivers for 7 USD before adding the shipping cost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Impossible because

- VOA Mandarin airwave transmission ended in 2011 ([story](https://www.heritage.org/global-politics/report/radio-silence-china-voa-abandons-the-airwaves)).
- BBC Chinese Service was shut down in 2011 ([story](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-pacific-12864041)).

---

Anyway, very few use radio signals nowadays. Nowadays, any "radio" station will be available online that one can easily access via VPN (in most places in the PRC including Beijing).

VOA Mandarin [here](https://www.voachinese.com/live/audio/46) (laggy for me) or [here](https://stream.radiojar.com/7thwu53r92quv) (via Radiojar, works well for me).

Comment: Are VPNs banned in China?

Comment: @H2ONaCl: No. There are restrictions but anyone who knows how to use a search engine can easily get around them (and also answer all the questions you've asked).

Comment: Interesting excerpt from one of your links... "If approved by Congress, ending shortwave transmissions to China would be the biggest blunder yet in the history of U.S. international broadcasting and public diplomacy.

In the next few minutes, I will try to put the BBG’s budget proposal into perspective and show you how I have come to this conclusion."

Comment: What VPN works in PRC? expensive?